# Merge two csv files and add a counter

Tags: csv, awk, merge, duplicates

I want to merge two csv files with the same number of rows and add a counter in the first column. For example, for the two input files:

**f1.csv**

```
a, b, c
d, e, f
```

**f2.csv**

```
aa, bb
dd, ee
```

I want to generate a file **f.csv** with

```
1, a, b, c, aa, bb
2, d, e, f, dd, ee
```

I have tried with:

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<2;i++){print ",", i, $1, $2}}' f1.csv f2.csv > f.csv
```

But it generates something like this:

```
1, a, b, c
2, d, e, f
1, aa, bb
2, dd, ee
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through paste and awk,

```
$ paste -d", " file1 /dev/null file2 | awk '{print NR", "$0}'
1, a, b, c, aa, bb
2, d, e, f, dd, ee
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR {a[NR]=$0;next} {print FNR", "a[FNR]", "$0}' f1 f2
1, a, b, c, aa, bb
2, d, e, f, dd, ee
```